# C++, forcing user input to use exactly 5 numbers and numbers only

Tags: input, numbers, integer, cin

So i am trying to write a code, where i will check if the input of minimum and maximum 5 numbers is a Palindrome. I have a problem verifying if the users input is only numbers, and to restrict it to exactly 5 numbers.

I have tried the cinfail but it allows 2h34j, by ignoring the letters. I want the program to check if all 5 characters are numbers, if not, restart the loop.

I can not use string nor char as variable. Only int.

Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, num = 0, siffra, rev = 0;
    const int inm = 0;
    cout << "Mata in ett femsifrigt heltal: ";
    cin >> num;
    n = num;
    do
    {
        siffra = num % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + siffra;
        num = num / 10;
    } while (num != 0);

    cout << " Inmatningen baklänges blir: " << rev << endl;

    if (n == rev)
        cout << " Nummret är en palindrom\n";
    else
        cout << " Numret är inte en palindrom\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every integer with exactly five significant digits is between 10000 and 99999, inclusive.  You can check whether the user entered a number in this range.  If you cannot input into `string`s or `char`s then I think such a range check is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

So i added the if checking the range, and also put in a loop. All good, except for when i write in a letter, then the program goes nuts and repeats all my couts without stopping. If i write in numbers, it will tell me that it should be 5 numbers, and loops back to cin, but as soon as i write in a letter, the loop of couts never ends. What could be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");
    while (true) {
        int n, num = 0, siffra, rev = 0;
        const int inm = 0;
        cout << "Mata in ett femsifrigt heltal: ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num >= 9999 && num <= 100000) {
            n = num;
            do
            {
                siffra = num % 10;
                rev = (rev * 10) + siffra;
                num = num / 10;
            } while (num != 0);

            cout << " Inmatningen baklänges blir: " << rev << endl;

            if (n == rev)
                cout << " Nummret är en palindrom\n";
            else {
                cout << " Numret är inte en palindrom\n";
            }
            char ch = 'n'; J/j
            cout << "Testa igen, [j/n] ? "; **// Yes or no option to restart the program**
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch == 'J' || ch == 'j') 

                continue;
            else
                break;
        }
        else; {
            cout << " Var vänlig mata in exakt 5 siffror, och inga andra tecken!\n";
            continue;  **//if the user writes to few numbers or too many, or uses letter, the program should reloop.**
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```